# Windows programming and key events: ALT key sound effect

Tags: c++, windows, desktop-application

Is there any way to prevent Windows from playing that annoying sound effect when the `alt` key is pressed in an app that *doesn't make use of it*?

My app is a 3D desktop C++ game that uses `WM_CHAR` and Direct Input (API needs upgraded) to make use of the ALT key. I am actually using the `ALT+*` commands in my program, but Windows has no way of knowing that. Is there any way to inform it so, to make it stop playing the sound effect?

Apologies if this has been asked before. I searched, but found nothing. I'm looking for a way to disable it within my program, rather than asking all of my users to disable the sound, for example.

Edit: After some research, it appears that handling `WM_SYSCHAR` will stop Windows from playing sounds, but it also blocks all of the standard windows functionality, such as ALT+F4 (Alt+Tab still works). I'm not a fan of this, so hoping someone knows of a simple method to stop the sound alone. I can manually handle ALT+F4, but can't imagine what other commands I'm likely blocking.

Comment: Mashing alt by itself a bunch of times is actually the language switcher in Windows by default.

Comment: If you receive the message, you may need to detect Alt+F4 and let that flow through to the default handler. It's hard to say without looking at your code.

Comment: @tadman Yeah, I could handle ALT+F4 that way, or even shut down manually. I'm mostly concerned about commands that I may not know about. The app can be used in window mode, and I'm assuming there is a whole slew of accessibility commands that I've never heard of. As well as things added in the future. It would probably work if I could just detect a specific command that my app will respond to, and send everything else to the default proc. But there's too many layers in the engine to pull that off in a reasonable way. The command may not even be registered until the next frame, for example.

Comment: To be honest, I've been dealing with that annoying ding for so long, the WM_SYSCHAR solution feels like magic. On top of the annoying sound, the alt key also sometimes completely freezes the focused app, which is also solved by handling WM_SYSCHAR. It may be worth handling most of the ALT commands manually just to avoid all of those side effects.