# Remove Windows Error/Beep sound when pressing Alt + Key combinations

Tags: c++, flutter, winapi

I am trying to remove windows error sound from my Flutter (Win32) Application. After some research I came up with this [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74998972/16841527). I tried this fix but it's not helping in my Flutter application.

Heres the code to handle `WM_SYSCHAR` message:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK Win32Window::WndProc(HWND const window,
                                      UINT const message,
                                      WPARAM const wparam,
                                      LPARAM const lparam) noexcept {
  if (message == WM_SYSCHAR) {
    std::cout << "SYSCHAR from win32" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
  ...
}
```

When I press the Alt+Space, "SYSCHAR from win32" is printed in the console. But whenever I press any other key with Alt, this is not printed and the Windows error sound is played. It seems like `SYSCHAR` message is handled somewhere else?

[This](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/hello_world/windows/runner) can be used to know the working and initialization of Win32 App in Flutter.

I just want to tell the Application that Alt+Key combinations are handled and it doesn't have to play Windows error sound.

Comment: This is conventionally handled using [keyboard accelerators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-keyboard-accelerators), but Flutter's [main loop](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/hello_world/windows/runner/main.cpp#L39-L43) is missing the call to `TranslateAccelerator`, so you cannot use that. At a guess the error sound is generated because the application is requesting keyboard input, but then fails to handle the `WM_CHAR` messages.

Comment: Thanks, I added keyboard accelerators in the main loop and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) for suggesting me to use [keyboard accelerators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-keyboard-accelerators).

The problem is Flutter's [main loop](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/hello_world/windows/runner/main.cpp#L39-L43) doesn't have keyboard accelerators. So I followed [how to use keyboard accelerators documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-keyboard-accelerators#creating-a-run-time-accelerator-table) and modified the main loop as follows:

1. Created accelerator table by calling [CreateAcceleratorTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createacceleratortablea)

```cpp
LPACCEL accels = GenerateAccels();
HACCEL haccel = CreateAcceleratorTable(accels, 36);
if (haccel==NULL) {
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Here's the `GenerateAccels` function:

```cpp
LPACCEL GenerateAccels() {
  LPACCEL lpAccel = new ACCEL[36];
  
  // Alt + Number combinations:
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    lpAccel[i].fVirt = FALT;
    lpAccel[i].key = (WORD)(0x30 + i);
  }

  // Alt + Alphabet combinations (NOT WORKING AT THE MOMENT):
  for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    lpAccel[i + 10].fVirt = FALT;
    lpAccel[i + 10].key = (WORD)(0x41 + i);
  }

  return lpAccel;
}
```

2. Then adding a call to [TranslateAccelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-translateacceleratora) in the [main loop](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/hello_world/windows/runner/main.cpp#L39-L43)

```cpp
::MSG msg = { };
while (::GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0) > 0) {
  if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, haccel, &msg)) {
    ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
    ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
}
```

3. I also added this check to prevent error sound from playing when any key is pressed after pressing Alt (Alt is not held down).

> `flutter_window.cpp`
>
> ```cpp
> case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
>   // If the selection is in menu
>   // handle the key event
>   // This prevents the error/beep sound
>   if (wparam == SC_KEYMENU) {
>     return 0;
>   }
> ```

*Note: One thing that isn't working is **Alt + Alphabet** combinations. When pressed, it is still playing that error sound. In my case it's not important right now, but if someone finds the fix then please share.*